# An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('moneda_moneda_id_seq')':

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, sequence, doctrine-orm-postgres

im getting this error while trying to insert an entity in symfony2 with doctrine2,

```
/**
 * Moneda
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="moneda")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Moneda
 {
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="moneda_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="moneda_moneda_id_seq", allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
     */
     private $monedaId;
```

I`ve check my database to check any typo erros but everything is in order so i don´t know what is wrong here so please any help will be appreciated.

this is the exception

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('moneda_moneda_id_seq')':

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: no existe la relación «moneda_moneda_id_seq»
LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('moneda_moneda_id_seq')

Comment: If you post the error that you are getting, it would be much more helpful. For example, does it say something like 'sequence does not exist'?

Comment: yeah sorry man, editting the question

Comment: but the sequence does exist man, ive check it in my database, by the way im using postgresql.

Comment: did you found a solution. Me pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue before.  You must include the schema name while referring to the sequence.  So try using something like this when defining your sequence:

```
@ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="schema_name.moneda_moneda_id_seq", allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
```

This is what solved my issue.  Hopefully it will work for you as well.